# how to add password to already existing zip file using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have created a ZIP file using ruby , now I have to add password to this file. But it is not working. Could someone help. I am using rubyzip and zip-zip gem.
Code which I tried as below :

```
#Create Zip File and delete if already existing
 filename= 'abc.xlsx'
                 zip_file_path = Rails.root.join('tmp/my.zip')  
                 file_name =filename
                 file_path = Rails.root.join('tmp', filename)  
                 logger.error zip_file_path
                 logger.error file_path

                 File.delete(zip_file_path) if File.exist?(zip_file_path)

                 Zip::ZipFile.open(zip_file_path, Zip::ZipFile::CREATE) do |zip|
                        zip.add(file_name, file_path)  
                 end        
   # end
```

Next step is to add password to ZIP file . I tried below method

```
 Zip::File.encrypt(zip_file_path, 'password')
     # Got error like : **NameError (uninitialized constant Zip::Archive):**
```

Also i tried to use below :

```
    Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer(::StringIO.new(''), Zip::TraditionalEncrypter.new('password')) do |out|
      out.put_next_entry("my_file.txt")
      out.write my_data
    end.string

#error: **NameError (uninitialized constant Zip::TraditionalEncrypter):**
```

Comment: "It's not working" -- **What's** not working? What have you tried? What result/error do you get?

Comment: Why is this tagged as `ruby-on-rails`, `ruby-on-rails-4` and  `ruby-on-rails-3.2`? Is rails relevant to the question? (Why?) And if so, which version are you actually using?

Comment: I am using below code :

Zip::OutputStream.write_buffer(::StringIO.new(''), Zip::TraditionalEncrypter.new('password')) do |out|
  out.put_next_entry("my_file.txt")
  out.write my_data
end.string

Getting below error 
NameError (uninitialized constant Zip::TraditionalEncrypter)

Comment: I am using rail version -- '3.2.13'

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50422601/edit) to include all relevant information; don't leave it buried in the comments. Which library are you using? (What is `Zip`?) Does rails actually bearing on the question/solution, or is superfluous information? If it's relevant, then explain why; if it's not, then there's no need to tag the question as such.